# Test case for my controller class using spring mvc testing with nested object params

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockmvc, integration-testing

Following is My controller class, I want to write spring mvc test cases for the below. I cannot understand how to pass parameter in my test class. I have googled enough, but unable to find proper solution.

So, now my problem is, while using MockMvc I need to know what I have to pass to this param ("problem is here","problem is here").

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
//MyController.java
public class MyController{
public String getResponse(@RequestBody LevelOneObj levelOneObject){
//Mycontroller code here
}
}

//LevelOneObj.java
public class LevelOneObj{
   LevelTwoObj levelTwoObj;
   String someValue;
}

//LevelTwoObj.java
public class LevelTwoObj{
   String id;
   String name;
  ///some code here
}
```